# Typing in a IFrame with Selenium IDE

Tags: iframe, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, typing

I'd like to type something in a IFrame with Selenium IDE but I don't know how to do this.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You have to select the iframe and then type

```
selenium.selectFrame("css=iframe.widget[<a_css_identifier>]");
selenium.type(<your_object_or_text_box>, <typed_content>);
```

The statements are in java, but you should be able to find `selectFrame` and `type` in the IDE.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Selenium IDE command 'selectFrame' to focus within an iframe. Use the Target field to enter the iframe id.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<tr> 
    <td>selectFrame</td> 
    <td>edit</td> 
    <td></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
    <td>type</td> 
    <td>xpath=//html/body</td> 
    <td>my text</td> 
</tr>
```