# type into iframe in selenium

Tags: java, iframe, selenium, selenium-rc, xpath

I need to type data into an `iframe`. I referred to

[Typing in a IFrame with Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515981/typing-in-a-iframe-with-selenium-ide/9903550#9903550)

but `selenium.selectFrame(<xpath>)` returns: `Element not found error` and no css has been defined for the `iframe`.

Using firebug:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" tabindex="0" src="" title="Rich text editor, templateWizardCKEditor1, press ALT 0 for help." style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"/>
```

What could be a solution for this?

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution for the same...

```
driver.switchTo().frame("ext-gen298");
WebElement editable = driver.switchTo().activeElement();
editable.sendKeys("Your text here");
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Ref: http://code.google.com/p/seleniumwikiFrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_type_into_a_contentEditable_iframe?

Answer (score 3):

That just means you used some bad xpath.

```
selenium.selectFrame("xpath=//iframe[contains(@title,'Rich text editor')]");
```

This should work. It selects the iframe based on an xpath expression that looks for an iframe which title attribute contains "Rich text editor".

For more xpaths, see [XPath v1.0 on w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) and [XPath v2.0 on w3.org - only for some browsers](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/).

By the way, the iframe can be selected by css selectors, too, even if it has no css assigned. The selector can select any element based on its position in tree hierarchy and it's attributes - similar to XPath. To learn about css selector, try [The w3 again](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_selector#Syntax)

Comment: selenium.selectFrame("xpath=//iframe[contains(@title,'Rich text editor')]"); 
selenium.type("xpath=//iframe[contains(@title,'Rich text editor')]", tag); 
But got Element not found error. So I tried 
selenium.selectFrame("xpath=//iframe[contains(@title,'Rich text editor, templateWizardCKEditor3, press ALT 0 for help.')]");
selenium.type("xpath=//iframe[contains(@title,'Rich text editor, templateWizardCKEditor3, press ALT 0 for help.')]", tag); but of no use.

Comment: Well if you want to write right into the iframe, that could be a problem. After the first `selectFrame()`, you can try [this method](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#getWhetherThisFrameMatchFrameExpression%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). Writing into editable iframes is tricky and can be done [with WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q:_How_do_I_type_into_a_contentEditable_iframe?) or by some JavaScript similar to the one shown there, I guess.

Comment: ...because when you do `selectFrame()`, you basically have that frame as your new root node. Meaning that if you want to write into the frame, you would need to call `selenium.type("xpath=/", tag);` ... and that might actually work, too! Give it a try :)

Comment: Huh! I'd like to get my hands on an reproducible example. If your page is proprietary, could you try to create one? Or what exactly is the `iframe` content? Other than that ... try the [Selenium Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/selenium-users).

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the frame first,
2. Then click it to separate the header information (WSYWG) from the text area,
3. Then focus on the text area (tinymce)
4. Then send your text to populate the field (we have 2 examples to show different objects that work)
5. Then select Window back to default window (null)

Here is what I used that worked:

```html
<td>selectFrame</td>
<td>xpath=//*[contains (@id, 'mce_0_ifr')]</td>
<td></td>

<td>click</td>
<td>xpath=//*[contains (@id, 'tinymce')]</td>
<td></td>

<td>focus</td>
<td>xpath=//*[contains (@id, 'tinymce')]</td>
<td></td>

<td>sendKeys</td>
<td>xpath=//*[contains (@id, 'tinymce')]</td>
<td>I Typed in an iFrame!!!</td>

<td>sendKeys</td>
<td>css=body#tinymce.mceContentBody</td>
<td>0</td>

<td>selectWindow</td>
<td>null</td>
<td></td>
```