# Selenium ide generated code does not indicate what frame

Tags: java, selenium, frame, selenium-ide

I have done several selenium recordings and played back in java and a common issue is that the play back will say find by locator of something and I would get an exception of **not found**.

It was because I was not on the right window or not in the right frame.

I was wondering if I am using the ide incorrectly or if there is an addon that adds lines to switch to the proper window and frame before you try to findbyId or findbyXpath.

I would have like the source to say switch to this window or frame before you do your find.

It seems others have seen something like this too as in

http://grokbase.com/t/gg/selenium-users/125ans2pjw/gmail-saw-it-in-silktest-how-do-i-do-it-in-selenium-ide

Comment: Your best bet may be to make sure the iframe has an id on it. See this thread for more information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9903788/type-into-iframe-in-selenium

Comment: True but I was assuming the the Selenium ID would generate the code to switch to that frame before executing a find. In my case there is NO switchto generated and I was wondering if I am doing something wrong or that is the way the tool works.

Comment: The Selenium IDE won't generate that kind of code. Each action that is recorded is recorded in isolation, without a history.